# Export npm JS package as independent script

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I'm using npm package manager for my project.

Dependency in my package.json file:

```
"dependencies": {
    "litepicker": "^2.0.11"
},
```

litepicker (javascript library)

File structure:

```
- assets
-- js
--- main.js
- index.php
```

How do I move litepicker js file into assets/js/ folder using npm script?

Comment: Why not remove it from package.json and include a call to it in your front-end code, because that's what it looks like you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

### 1. You can use [laravel-mix](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/mix#running-mix)

if you don't use laravel framework

you still can use laravel-mix
[Sitepoint - Use Laravel Mix for non Laravel Project](https://www.sitepoint.com/use-laravel-mix-non-laravel-projects/)

It's bit complex since u need to deal with other stuff. And there is another option too

### 2. Use CDN from [unpkg](https://unpkg.com/) or [JSDelivr](https://www.jsdelivr.com/)

*unpkg is a fast, global content delivery network for everything on npm. Use it to quickly and easily load any file from any package using a URL like*

[Example unpkg - https://newbedev.com/php-sweet-alert-in-js-laravel-8-code-example](https://newbedev.com/php-sweet-alert-in-js-laravel-8-code-example)

[Codepen Litepicker using JSDelivr](https://codepen.io/nyroDev/pen/LYbJpqK?editors=1010)

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/litepicker/dist/litepicker.js"></script>
```